# /etc/resolv.conf overwritten with old DNS entries not what is in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3

Tags: dns, oracle-linux

I have an Oracle Linux 7.5 VM on VirtualBox setup with a static IP address. My DNS servers have changed since I first setup the VM. I modified the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` to have the IP address for the new DNS server but, when I reboot, `/etc/resolv.conf` keeps getting recreated with the old DNS server ip addresses.

```
[root@oel72 ~]# cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
[root@oel72 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-enp0s3
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=58524328-dc73-4b1f-9a56-e3a5d5a4edd5
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
DNS1=IPADDRESSOFNEWDNSSERVER
DOMAIN="my domains edited for post"
IPADDR=10.0.2.6
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=10.0.2.2
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
```

```
[root@oel72 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager

search my domains edited for post
nameserver IPADDRESSOFOLDDNS1
nameserver IPADDRESSOFOLDDNS2
nameserver IPADDRESSOFOLDDNS3
```

I edited out the actual IP addresses and actual domain names. Hopefully that will not obscure the issue. I'm guessing that there is some command to make the system pull in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` again and that it will store the IP address for the new DNS but I cannot find instructions for doing so. Does anyone know how to update these?

Comment: Is any DNS configured in `/etc/sysconfig/network`?

Comment: No, that file is empty. [root@oel72 sysconfig]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
# Created by anaconda

Comment: A couple of sites recommended that I run chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf. This seems to work but seems like a kludge or hack.

Comment: You may try using NetworkManager to set your DNS URLs/addresses. I'm not sure you'll find it on Oracle Linux, but `nmtui` is an easy way to do it from the command line. NetworkManager uses plugins to read/write network configuration files, but it doesn't monitor them.

Comment: I tried a variety of nmcli commands without success. I think nmcli is the command line equivalent of nmtui. It just seems like the DNS ip addresses are stored somewhere and no command will shake them loose.

Comment: Random suggestions (being short of good ones): 1) check if NetworkManager settings in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` differ from the default: the documentation (`man 5 NetworkManager.conf`) lists several and possibly convoluted ways to manage `resolv.conf`. 2) Use `auditd` to check which program is editing your `resolv.conf`. 3) If applicable, prevent NetworkManager from modifying `resolv.conf` (again, refer to `man Networkmanager.conf`, especially the `dns` and `rc-manager` keys).

Comment: I tried adding dns=none in a file in /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d but it did not do anything. Really, I guess using chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf is kind of the same thing. Just lock it down so it can't change. Everything was commented out in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and I'm pretty sure it is the default.